# PHP 5.3.1 Undefined Symbol: OnUpdateLong error on Apache Startup

Tags: apache-2.2, php

I'm running Ubuntu 8.04 on this server. I had PHP 5.2 installed via the package manager. I removed it to install PHP 5.3.1 by hand. I built the packages like so

```
./configure --prefix=/opt/php --with-mysql --with-curl=/usr/bin --with-apxs2=/usr/bin/apxs2
make
make install
```

This installed PHP 5.3.1 in /opt/php/

```
$ php -v
PHP 5.3.1 (cli) (built: Dec  7 2009 10:51:14) 
Copyright (c) 1997-2009 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v2.3.0, Copyright (c) 1998-2009 Zend Technologies
```

However, when I try to start Apache I get this.

```
 # /etc/init.d/apache2 restart
 * Restarting web server apache2       
  apache2: Syntax error on line 185 of /etc/apache2/apache2.conf: 
  Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.load: 
  Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so into server: 
  /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so: undefined symbol: OnUpdateLong
                                                                     [fail]
```

Any ideas what's causing this error? All the references I can see have to do with building php5 packages for php4 or the like. PHP4 has never been installed on this machine.

Answer (score 11):

actually, what James Hackett said was more or less what worked for me.

My problem wasa that I built PHP **before** I installed Apache (I built PHP from latest trunk and installed Apache2 via APT).

So when I encountered the error that apache encountered an undefined symbol (the module which is not found is arbitrary btw.), I did the following:

1. `make distclean` on the php source
2. `./configure --prefix=/usr/local/php-5.3-svn --with-apxs2=/usr/bin/apxs2`
3. `make && make install`

and everything worked just fine.

Captain obvious was hiding from me, of course since if you just remake without make distclean && configure, make just compiles the new symbols which obviously is not enough ;-)

Answer (score 3):

I had this same problem and what I did was delete my php source directory, re-extract the tarball and then compile again and everything worked fine.

I had previously installed php on this system without apache and then I had tried reinstalling php from the same source directory with different config settings.

Answer (score 1):

You built php5 but you did'nt rebuilt the glue between apache and php5. Since you are using mod_php5, it fails (logical).

You may be able to run php script thanks to fastcgi (I assume your built-by-hand php 5.3.1 is ok), but anyway I recommend you to act in another manner.

That's pretty nasty to build a software by hand on a production server.
Moreover PHP5 is a big piece of software, you really should **not** do that for maintenance and security purposes.

The correct way to achieve this, if you really need that version, is to backport the package.
(yes, packaging !)

It require a bit of packaging knowledge and time.
You can get the packaging sources with: `apt-get source php5`, provided you have a deb-src source in /etc/apt/sources.list

Comment: It's not a production server. It's just our dev server and I'm trying to figure out what, if anything php 5.3 will break in our system.

Comment: "That's pretty nasty to build a software by hand on a production server. Moreover PHP5 is a big piece of software, you really should not  do that for maintenance and security purposes."  On most distributions it's the only way to stay up-to-date.  Ubuntu for example, only has 5.2.10 as stable in its repositories which was released back in June 2009.  Personally I find it more of a security risk to use pre-packages because they have a lot of extra stuff built in that you may not need and can strip out if you build them yourself. Plus you can keep up-to-date.

Answer (score 1):

for those of you experienceing the zend_parse_paramater error from apache2, while loading libphp5.so:

/apache2.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/php5.load: Cannot load /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so into server: /usr/lib/apache2/modules/libphp5.so: undefined symbol: zend_parse_parameters

take a look at the ./configure output.  if you get a message saying something similar to:

configure: warning: bison versions supported for regeneration of the Zend/PHP parsers: 1.28 1.35 1.75 1.875 2.0 2.1 2.2 2.3 2.4 2.4.1 (found: none).

try installing bison: sudo apt-get install bison

then make distclean
then ./configure ...
then make
then make -i install

http://www.linuxforums.org/forum/redhat-fedora-linux-help/87975-configuring-php-work-apache.html

Comment: It should only be necessary to rebuild the zend parsers if you've modified the PHP source code in some way. I've never installed bison on any production servers and never had a problem.

Answer (score 0):

As @zecrazytux indicated, did you install the appropriate apache-dev packages? PHP could well have built without them, even though you told it where they were. You need to look at the ./configure output.